# Convergence of a power series at an endpoint

Tags: convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Suppose we have some function $f$ that is $C^\infty$ on some interval $J \subseteq \mathbb R$. We choose a point $x_0$ and compute the Taylor series $\sum a_n (x-x_0)^n$.  Next, we calculate the radius of convergence $r$, so we know the series converges (absolutely and uniformly) to some function $g$ on $(x_0 - r, x_0 + r)$.  Finally, we compute the Taylor remainder $R_n(x)$ and show that it converges to zero within $(x_0 - r, x_0 + r)$.  We conclude that $f = g$ on $(x_0 - r, x_0 + r)$.

So far, so good.  Now we turn to consider endpoint behavior, and we verify that our Taylor series converges at one of our endpoints -- say, at $x_0 + r$.  (That is, we confirm that the series $\sum a_n r^n$ converges.)  Are we justified in concluding that $\sum a_n r^n = f(x_0 + r)$?

That is:

> If a Taylor series converges to $f$ inside an open interval, and it converges (to something) at one of the endpoints of the interval, does it necessarily converge to $f$ at the endpoint?

Or to put it another way:

> Can a Taylor series converge to $f$ inside an open interval but converge to *something else* at one (or both) of the interval's endpoints?

My instinct is that if the series converges at an endpoint, it must agree with $f$ there; I feel that there is an elementary argument, relying solely on the facts that

1. The original function $f$ is continuous at $x_0 + r$
2. The limit of the series is continuous inside $(x_0 - r, x_0 + r)$
3. The two functions agree inside $(x_0 - r, x_0 + r)$

...but for some reason I can't see how to connect the dots to reach the conclusion that the two functions agree at $x_0 + r$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_theorem. They state the result for power series with a radius of convergence of $1$, but I'm sure it can be generalized to any radius of convergence.